# Wordpress Inner Pages throw 404 on Laravel Site

Tags: wordpress, laravel-4

I installed wordpress on laravel site and Everythign is working fine on Laravel pages,WP Dashboard and WP Home page except on Wp inner pages which are giving me a 404 error.

I installed wordpress inside laravel directory called public/blogs.

Here's the htaccess on public/

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And here's the htaccess on public/blogs wp installation

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blogs/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [S=35]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

And I have a code which filters 404 page on laravel Filer file. 
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Check your permalink. Reset your permalinks. You need to login and then on dashboard ->settings->permalinks. In that select default and save it once. Later change it to Post name and save it. Check if it still gives 404 error.

Comment: @Pranita that works but whenever I changed it to friendly permalinks, 404 shows up again on inner pages. If you can give me an idea on how to properly configured a NGINX rewrite rule for this setup (wp on laravel site) I will really appreciate that. thanks